# Cant go back until the whole page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

i have an auto generate php gallery that preload all the images while the thumbnails are loading.. it load one thumb and after preload the actual image with it.. the problem is that i cant go back until i click the stop loading button..

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
if (document.images) {
    img1 = new Image();
    img1.src ="../album/1000";
}
</script>
```

this is the preloading script and this is the back button script:

```
<div id="topbar"  style="display: block;">
    <div id="leftnav">
            <a href="../mindex.php">Go back</a></div></div>
```

the thing is i found how to stop the loading on clicking the go back button but it wont load my page or go to the href.. 
thanks ahead

Answer (score 1):

Try Putting the part that loads the images in a function which is called just after the page is loaded. Something like this:

```
<script>
  function load(){
     // some loading script
  }
</script>
<body onload="load();">
```

This means that your page will load all the html, but everything on the screen, and just then call the 'load' function. This could make the page look a little wired until everything is loaded. But the browser should respond.

Comment: but the problem is that the gallery is automate, the php script auto put the pictures in it so i have to use preload in my php and not in the head of the page because i need it to generate the files name..

Answer (score 0):

Wow i cant believe it was that simple:\ i tried so many things!!!
my stupid solution is to add

```
<a href="your/link/" target="_self" onclick="window.stop();"></a>
```

to the link.. i forgot that i have this script who prevent my pages to open new tabs because its a web app..